# Clone a repo inside a docker shared folder after being mounted

Tags: git, docker, dockerfile

Is there a way to clone a repo inside a Docker shared folder after the folder was mounted?

For exemple, if I do it in the `Dockerfile`, it's correctly cloned. But, then, the folder inside the container is overridden by the local one once it's being mounted.

Is there another way?

Comment: Do you use docker volumes?

Comment: Yes, a folder shared with a local folder at the root of my project

Comment: Could you please share your `Dockerfile` and you `docker run` instructions? Just to get sure about your steps.

Answer (score 0):

Either the repo is part of the `Dockerfile` and therefore the image or it is mounted into the running container.

What you may want to do is to use an `ENTRYPOINT` that executes a script in the container that clones the repo into the (then) mounted folder. Beware the overhead of cloning the repo every single time though.

You could also clone the repo in the `Dockerfile` into some location and use an `ENTRYPOINT`-script to clone from that location to it's final (mounted) destination and do a `pull`; only changes need to be retransmitted every time a container is started then.